# Is this joining coffeescript classes over files a valid aproach?

Tags: class, coffeescript

I want to join (use) classe in Coffescript files, and i found some usefull ideas here (sry for not including all links), since none fitted my needs (at least not as i like) I tried to find an own solution, this will work fine, **but** is there something I have overseen?

following "base" and "base class" are not OO words, I just did not find better names

I have a base (class) file TechDraw

```
class TechDraw
  constructor: ->
    $(window).load () =>
    ... do somthing

  wave_to_me: ->
    say 'I wave'   # say is a basic func, I always use for debugging (console.log)

@TechDraw = new TechDraw
```

this works fine

Now I want to expand/extend my class with "sub classes/modules" in other files; ie. I have a TechDrawLine, and a TechDrawCalc, ans so on

What I did, was building a coffee file for each of them like:

```
class TechDrawConnector
   constructor: (p)->
      @parent=p

    wave: (msg) -> 
      say 'yes its me, the connector:',msg 

`window.TechDrawConnector = function(p) { return new TechDrawConnector(p) };`
# the last instead of a simple new  like
# @TechDrawConnector = new TechDrawConnector
```

and my base(ic) class/module I extendet like this:

```
class TechDraw
  constructor: ->
    $(window).load () =>
       @Connector=window.TechDrawConnector(this) 
       @LineGuy=window.TechDrawLineGuy(this) 


       @Connector.wave('init')
```

Since I am a newbee in coffeescript (yes javascript also) my solution feels to simple ...

Have I overseen somthing? The Polution of the global namespace is not so bad I think

Comment: what do you mean by "extend the base class (TechDraw)" Do you overwrite that in another file?

Comment: @robkuz: you are right, "extend" is not the right word. "Expand" would be a better*. The idea is not to have inheritance, than to split the logic in seperate CoffeeScript files and not to poulute the public namespace. (*)its hard to find words, that are not Umis)leading to OO anyhow :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cant create an "extension" that way.

If you define the same class in the same namespace a second time the first class will simply be overwritten and become in accessible. This will mostly be dependent on the order of loading of the compiled JavaScript files.

However you could either later add an method to the prototype of the class

```
#file a.coffee
class A
    constructor: ->
        @foo()

#file B.coffee
A::foo = -> #do something
```

However this is no good style and can certainly be very confusing some time and lead to brittle errors.

Better would be to use a form of dependency injection

```
#file a.coffee
class A
    constructor: (@closure) ->
        $(window).load () => @closure()


#file B.coffee
new A () ->
   @Connector=window.TechDrawConnector(@) 
   @LineGuy=window.TechDrawLineGuy(@) 
   @Connector.wave('init')
```

Comment: did I miss a speciality behind "@closure"?

Comment: "@closure" isnt special at all. I could have also named that thing x. It was only because it is a closure